# HTML and attachment issue in order confirmation email - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email

When someone placed an **order** on the website, they received a order confirmation email  and its works, **but the problem** is its coming as **attachment email** and **HTML format** to show on the email so my question is how to i stop it from coming as an attachment i just want it to be HTML with out the download part.

Answer (score 0):

First check please that your template in: `app/locale/language_ISO/template/email/sales/order_new.html` is correct and there are no errors, if so Try this:

Create **app/etc/modules/YourNameSpace_EmailFormat.xml** and add to , so your config is loaded last:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNameSpace_EmailFormat>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Contacts/>
                <AW_Blog/>
            </depends>
        </YourNameSpace_EmailFormat>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/YourNameSpace/EmailFormat/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNameSpace_EmailFormat>
            <version>1</version>
        </YourNameSpace_EmailFormat>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <template>
            <email>
                <sales_email_order_template>
                    <type>text</type> //to change the type from html to text
                </sales_email_order_template>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

If you converts plain text emails to HTML, dont forget to change variables from `{{var foo.bar}}` to `{{htmlescape var=$foo.bar}}`